# IIS Home Directory path drive letters got changed on all my sites?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

Today in IIS I came into my server and all of my drive letters were changed from D: to E:?

Hacked I guess?  Anyone ever have this happen to them?

Windows 2003 Server, only 2 drives in the Machine C:, D:.  I have not touched the machine and the Drive Letter itself did not change just the setting in IIS for site Home Directory that point to it.

IE:

```
D:\websites\mywebsite.com
```

was changed to

```
E:\websites\mywebsite.com
```

Comment: Are these drives local to each server, or a network share mounted as a drive?

Comment: local drives only

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any drives at all, for instance having a USB drive plugged in during the boot operation? That might cause drive letter reassignment.

You may be able to change the relevant partition back from E: to D: using the disk manager in the computer management control panel.

It would be worth adding to your question the version+variant of Windows you have installed and and details you have about your drive arrangement (i.e. the info displayed in the disk management screen).

Comment: Disk names did not change,  I added additional tags - thanks!